# How to define a maximum zoom level for ol.control.ZoomToExtent?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

For layers with small extents it's sometimes useful to limit the zoom levels when zooming to their extents. For that, the `fit` method of `ol.View` has an option `maxZoom` ehich works very nice, for example:

```
map.getView().fit(ol.proj.transformExtent(mapExtent, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), map.getSize(), { maxZoom:18});
```

How can I achieve this for `ol.control.ZoomToExtent`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible see [zoomtoextentcontrol.js#L77](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/control/zoomtoextentcontrol.js#L77)